# Filter data according to the folder name and send to corresponding folder

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a package in which data is coming from SQL Server tables have data from all the states of the country (India). In the package first all the states names are pulled using SQL task and kept in a obj variable.

Then using for each loop container with ado enumerator and the obj variable we are creating folders for all the states and sending the data to a CSV file using data flow task. Inside the data flow task there is a ADO.NET connection source where the SQL command is used to pull the data of transactions and store in a  flat file.

My issue is the transactions of all states are going to that CSV file and in all the states folders same data is going.

How to filter the data using the state name and pass it to the corresponding state folder?

Comment: Within your ForEach loop, you have a data flow. You issue the same? query every iteration and just want to filter the data so if Col1 has Kerala, it flows to the Kerala folder and if it's Orissa, it just goes no where (until the current state is Orissa?)

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I would take. There are likely optimizations that can be done but I don't have enough information to implement them.

I envision an Execute SQL Task -> Foreach Loop Container. Inside the Container, a File System Task => Data Flow task

[image]

## Variables

This might be the most important part as this is where the majority of the logic is implemented.

[image]

I create 6 variables

- rsStates Object  This object will receive the results (recordset) of the Execute SQL Task.
- CurrentState String Initialize it with anything you like but I chose "XXX"
- FileExtension String Use whatever the resulting file should have. I chose ".txt"
- FolderBase String This should point to the root folder of where data will go. I chose "C:\ssisdata\output\SO_76340277"  Note the trailing slash in the value as this is important when we concatenate strings in the next step
- FolderCurrent String In the Expression, we want to use `@[User::FolderBase] +  @[User::CurrentState] +"\\"`  This results in a value of "C:\ssisdata\output\SO_76340277\XXX" Again, there is a trailing slash to the path
- CurrentOutputFileName String This too will use an Expression. I used `@[User::FolderCurrent] +  @[User::CurrentState] +  @[User::FileExtension]`  The result of this concatenation is "C:\ssisdata\output\SO_76340277\XXX\XXX.txt"  The CurrentState in the expression is the file name so edit as needed

## SQL Load States

I have an Execute SQL Task with a Full Result Set.

In the Result Set tab, I mapped Result Name `0`, Variable Name `User::rsStates`

### Query

Grabbing a list of states from Wikipedia, yields something like this

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
VALUES ('')
, ('Andhra Pradesh')
, ('Arunachal Pradesh')
, ('Assam')
, ('Bihar')
, ('Chhattisgarh')
, ('Goa')
, ('Gujarat')
, ('Haryana')
, ('Himachal Pradesh')
, ('Jharkhand')
, ('Karnataka')
, ('Kerala')
, ('Madhya Pradesh')
, ('Maharashtra')
, ('Manipur')
, ('Meghalaya')
, ('Mizoram')
, ('Nagaland')
, ('Odisha')
, ('Punjab')
, ('Rajasthan')
, ('Sikkim')
, ('Tamil Nadu')
, ('Telangana')
, ('Tripura')
, ('Uttar Pradesh')
, ('Uttarakhand')
, ('West Bengal')
)D(states)
WHERE D.states <> '';
```

## Foreach Loop Container

Configured as a Foreach ADO Enumerator. ADO object source variable is `User::rsStates`
Variable Mappings tab: User::CurrentState is Index 0

At this point, run the package and confirm the Execute SQL Task and the Foreach loop container work as expected as many people get hung up on these tasks.

## File System Task

I have a File System Task set to Create Directory if it does not exist. It is driven by the variable User::FolderCurrent

[image]

Run again and you should see the folders created if they weren't already there. And we've just proved that our enumerator is correctly pulling the state value from our record set and our variables are working as intended.

[image]

## Data Flow Task

The trick to filtering is the middle two components in this sample. It could be done in one but I have reasons for using two.

[image]

### OLE DB Source

I assume there's a reason you're not applying the filter (parameters) at this point, maybe you're working with a source that doesn't readily support filtering (text files, some API, etc)

I modified the original query to have an additional column, CurrentDate

```
SELECT
*, getdate() AS CurrentDate
FROM
(
VALUES ('')
, ('Andhra Pradesh')
, ('Arunachal Pradesh')
, ('Assam')
, ('Bihar')
, ('Chhattisgarh')
, ('Goa')
, ('Gujarat')
, ('Haryana')
, ('Himachal Pradesh')
, ('Jharkhand')
, ('Karnataka')
, ('Kerala')
, ('Madhya Pradesh')
, ('Maharashtra')
, ('Manipur')
, ('Meghalaya')
, ('Mizoram')
, ('Nagaland')
, ('Odisha')
, ('Punjab')
, ('Rajasthan')
, ('Sikkim')
, ('Tamil Nadu')
, ('Telangana')
, ('Tripura')
, ('Uttar Pradesh')
, ('Uttarakhand')
, ('West Bengal')
)D(states)
WHERE D.states <> '';
```

### Derived Column

Here we want to match whether the value in the column `states` is exactly equal to the variable value `[User::CurrentState]`

I will name the column IsMatch and use the following expression

```
states == @[User::CurrentState]
```

The reason I advocate doing this in two steps is simple. If the CurrentState is kerala and the value from the source is Kerala, we will not match. Exact match means it is a case sensitive match. If you need to worry about casing then you should apply some logic to both sides, like

```
LOWER(states) == LOWER(@[User::CurrentState])
```

The result is that every row that flows through this component will have a True or False value associated to it. In the event you get an unexpected match/non-match, you can inspect this column and work back to what the value was of your two inputs were and figure out why the match went awry (leading/trailing space, etc)

### Conditional Split

This is where the data is finally filtered. In the Condition column add `!IsMatch` which is "not is match"  and I labeled my Output Name as Unmatched. We're not going to do anything with the Unmatched output path, just let it flow to nothing.

[image]

What we care about is the "Conditional Split Default Output" path. Flow that to  the Flat File Destination.

### Flat File Destination

This is just a simple flat file with the columns "states" and "CurrentDate"

At this point, if you run the package, everything will work but the content of the output file will be the content of final state, likely West Bengal.

## Connection Managers

The remaining piece is to tell the destination Flat File Connection Manager that it needs to be dynamic and reflect the value of the CurrentState variable which conveniently enough is expressed through the variable User::CurrentOutputFileName

Right click on the Output Flat File Connection Manager and choose Properties. In the Properties window, find the Expressions section and click the ellipses `...` Select "ConnectionString" on the left side and use `@[User::CurrentOutputFileName]` on the right side.

Now when the package runs, the Foreach enumerator will change the value of CurrentState with each loop. That have a chain reaction to change the value of FolderCurrent which in turn changes the value of CurrentOutputFileName  The data in the Data Flow task will be filtered by the value of the CurrentState as well so you should be set.

## Results

Asking the file system to show all the contents of my FolderBase variable, I can see it created the directories and the each directory has a .txt file corresponding to the data in it.

[image]

Looking at the contents of files shows I have what I would have expected

```
C:\ssisdata\Output\SO_76340277\Kerala>type Kerala.txt
Kerala,2023-05-26 08:55:04.470000000

C:\ssisdata\Output\SO_76340277\Kerala>type ..\Punjab\Punjab.txt
Punjab,2023-05-26 08:55:05.770000000
```